# Equivalent in bash string substitution of this sed substitution

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

What would be the equivalent bash substitution of this sed substitution?

```
STRING="HELLO-MY-NAME-IS"
$ echo $STRING | sed 's/-/%2d/g'
HELLO%2dMY%2dNAME%2dIS
```

I have tried with this, but only applies to the first substring found:

```
$ echo ${STRING/"-"/"%2d"}
HELLO%2dMY-NAME-IS
```

Thanks

Comment: Did the answer help to you? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You may give a try to:

```
$ echo ${STRING//-/%2d}
HELLO%2dMY%2dNAME%2dIS
```

Note that you were using a single slash after `STRING`, while it is needed two of them to have a global replacement.

```
               .
$ echo ${STRING/-/%2d}
HELLO%2dMY-NAME-IS
               ..    
$ echo ${STRING//-/%2d}
HELLO%2dMY%2dNAME%2dIS
```